# Update object attribute in array but view is not effected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I develop app with angularJS.
That I have array of object.
WHen click on button, then call controller.clicked function
to update some attribute in of object in array.

But value show on view is not updated.

Then I try to update value in $timeout() but it is not worked.

How can i fix it?

```
    $scope.closeItemTab = function (itemTab) {
        //ensure the code will be called in a single $apply block.
        $timeout(function () {

            var epi;
            var len = $scope.itemList.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                epi = $scope.itemList[i];
                epi.active = false;
                if (epi.paadm_admno === itemTab.paadm_admno) {
                    $scope.itemList.splice(i, 1);
                    i--; //reduce index to current element.
                }
                len = $scope.itemList.length;
            }

            //active lasted tab.
            if ($scope.itemList.length > 0) {
                epi = $scope.itemList[$scope.itemList.length - 1];
                epi.active = true; //<<force to show 'active' class in view.
            }

        });
    };

===My view is==========================================================

<div ng-repeat="item in itemList" ng-click="closeItemTab(item)">
    Hide record #{{item.id}}
</div>

<tr ng-repeat="item in itemList" ng-class="{'active':item.active}">
    <td>{{item.firstname}} {{item.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{item.active}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please post your view as well

Comment: console errors ? is it work without `$timeout` ?

Comment: @Toress, Yes I try without $timeout, but not difference.

Comment: What are you using to trap the click event - probably not ng-click I suspect?

Comment: Sure, I use ng-click.
I found that if I delete item in array under $timeout, then it work perfectly. But it not work when try to update object attribute in array.